# Limit Database List to Ones With Permission SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-permissions, database-security

By default if you connect to a remote SQL Server via an account that has access to say 1 of the 10 databases.  You will still see in the Object Explorer all other databases, obviously due to permissions you cannot actually query them, but you can see their names.

I have heard that there is a method that disable this behavior, but I've been unable to find the answer, does anyone know how to do this?  To give an example I have a SQL Server called MyDbServer, it has 4 databases,

1. MyDatabase
2. YourDatabse
3. PrivateDatabase
4. ReallyPrivateDb

If you connect via an account that only has permissions to "YourDatabse" you will still see a listing of all other databases, attempts to query will grant "select" permission denied or a similar error.

For security resons, we DO NOT want users to see any database other than the ones they are mapped to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20061014155556/http://blogs.msdn.com/euanga/archive/2006/05/04/585513.aspx) talks about methods for hiding DBs for both SQL 2000 and SQL 2005.

Answer (score 1):

After having my client struggle with the identified resources I did some testing and created [this blog posting](https://web.archive.org/web/20081019021936/http://www.mitchelsellers.com/blogs/articletype/articleview/articleid/260/limit-sql-server-database-list.aspx) with a bit more context and instruction on how to get this working.

Comment: It appears that the downside is that only one user at a time can be the dbo.  Therefore, the client can only have 1 database user...  Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

The short of it is:

```
use master
go
deny VIEW any DATABASE to login1
go
```

where login1 is the login account that you want to limit.

Comment: Actually this doesn't get it all the way, the blog article, was a bit hard to follow, but the key is that the user must be DBO of the article in question

Comment: It would be nice if in SQL Server Management Studio if you could right click on a database and say show only this database for this profile. But it would never be that easy. My scenario is when I log onto my SQL Server at Godaddy using SQL Server Management Studio I see hundreds of other databases and have to scroll down everytime. Next time I will name my database "_AAAMydatabase"