# Speed up SQL Management Studio's Object Explorer on a shared hosting SQL Server environment

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

When I expand the "databases"-folder in the Object Explorer in SQL Management Studio Express it tends to load ALL databases that exists on my shared host. This results in very long delays (the app freezes totally and sometimes also crashes).

I just need to see the object tree of one database.

Is there any way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arvixe have posted a solution that makes the loading of databases very much faster.

[Take a look at it here](http://blog.arvixe.com/how-to-fix-the-the-server-principal-is-not-able-to-access-the-database-error-in-microsoft-sql-server-management-studio/), if you're interested.

Comment: My problem is right at arvixe. and it worked! why does that help? btw that is a problem with ssms right?! Is that a way to let a db user see only the dbs he is granted to see?

Comment: @ClayKaboom not sure since I don't use Arvixe anymore. Their support team might have an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps.

Run  this: `DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO public` and hope the login you are using is dbo...

[Example 1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsecurity/thread/a989ca87-660d-41c4-9dac-70b29a83ddfb/) and [SO Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201292/limit-database-list-to-ones-with-permission-sql-server)